# Access Firebase PhoneAuth Provider in XCTest Class Xcode

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, xctest, xctestcase

I'm trying to access the firebase phone authenticate delegate in the XCTest class.

**Code:-**

```
func testVerifyCorrectPhoneNumber(){
    FirebaseAuth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber("verificationPhone", uiDelegate: nil) { verificationID, error in
        XCTAssert((verificationID != nil) == false)
    }
}
```

**Error:-**

> Instance member 'verifyPhoneNumber' cannot be used on type 'PhoneAuthProvider'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

**Screenshot:-**

[image]

Can someone please explain to me how to access the firebase phone authenticate delegate in the XCTest Class, I've tried to with above code but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create NsObject And Access It.

**Code:-**

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase


class Access_Method_Clss : NSObject, ObservableObject {

override init() {
    let settings = FirestoreSettings()
    settings.isPersistenceEnabled = true
    self.db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.settings = settings
}

static let sharedInstance: Access_Method_Clss = {
    let instance = Access_Method_Clss()
    // in case we need to setup up
    return instance
}()

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Access_Method_Clss, Never>()

func verifyPhone(verificationPhone: String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void = { verificationID, error in }) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(verificationPhone, uiDelegate: nil) { verificationID, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("PhoneAuthProvider error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        completion(verificationID, error)
    }
}

func signIn(id: String, code: String, completion: @escaping (String?, Error?,Bool) -> Void) {
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: id, verificationCode: code)
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion("", error,false)
        }
        if let result = authResult {
            print("Check User id Valid or not = ",result.user.uid)
            self.checkProfileNeedToSetupOrNot(userID:  result.user.uid) { (response) in
                if response == false {
                    completion(result.user.uid, error,false)
                }else{
                    Analytics.logEvent("verification_completed", parameters: nil)
                    completion(result.user.uid, error,true)
                }
              }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

**Use:-**

```
func verifyPhoneNumberAndLogin(OtpEndrdCode:String,verificationID:String completion: @escaping(Bool,Bool) -> Void) {
if OtpEndrdCode != "" {
    Access_Method_Clss.signIn(id: verificationID, code: OtpEndrdCode) { newUserID,error,needToStp  in
        if let error = error {
            completion(false,false)
        } else {
            completion(true, true)
        }
    }
}else{
    completion(false,false)
  }
}
```